# How to make trigger works, if there is a predefined template

Tags: sql, oracle, select, triggers, package

In an ERP system we have a package which can generate a trigger according to a few parameters. We have an option to use SQL validation for the trigger, so I can write one select statement. I want a trigger which fires when the new document has a null value in a specific column. In the ERP system, the user can make a new order document (it has head+contents). The problem is, that the trigger fires when inserting... (INSERT OR UPDATE), so if the user "opens" a new document, the trigger will fire, because the value is null.. and before that, the value can't be passed...

The generated trigger code:

```
trigger T_V_ORDRS_H BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE 
on ORDRS_H 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW 

Declare
  nCount Number;
Begin 
  if INSERTING then 
    Select count(*) into nCount -- here goes the select statment as parameter  ;

    if nCount = 0 then
      c_exc.raiseerrormsg(GetResPar('%s errormessage !¤34357', 'DELIVERYNUMBER'));
 --function the raise error + the parameter goes into erroressage
    end if;
  end if; 

  if UPDATING then 

    if (:old.DELIVERYNUMBER != :new.DELIVERYNUMBER) or (:old.DELIVERYNUMBER is null and :new.DELIVERYNUMBER is not null) or (:old.DELIVERYNUMBER is not null and :new.DELIVERYNUMBER is null) then 
      Select count(*) into nCount   -- here goes the same select statment as parameter ;
      if nCount = 0 then
        c_exc.raiseerrormsg(GetResPar('%s errormessage !¤34357', 'DELIVERYNUMBER'));
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end;
```

First, i have to write a query, which count = 0 (NOT > 0 ). It's a bit hard for me...

So i tried, it works when it's inserting.. I find a workound and I eliminate the error. But if it's updating, it it doesn't work as it should.. because if the value was null, and want to update to anything else, it's not allowing to update it..

Here is my query:

```
from ordrs_h where 
PK=:new.PK 
and :new.type!='00028' 
and :new.deliverynumber is not null 
and :new.partner=partner or :new.partner=0   
-- so here with partner i can avoid trigger, when user is opening a new document (baceuse the partner is there 0)
```